# Integer data in -> averaged -> float data out in python for large files

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a large amount of data from a sensor represented as integers from 0-255 in a column of length 2048, and there are at least 10000 rows in the same 2D numpy array. I wish to average all of the rows together to obtain a column of floats and plot them. Simple, right?

When there was less than 1000 rows, my graph looked beautiful and not very quantized at all. Averaging was obvious.
When there was more than 10000 rows, my graph looked worse - more quantized-looking than the average of the smaller array, even though it was all made out of floats, it was so close to integers, it hurt.

What I'm asking is: why that might be the case? Averaging should "smooth out" sensor measurements. They are now more noisy (and quantized) when I take a longer data sample!

Here's an example of my current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lower_bound=0
upper_bound=2048

#this loads data into raw_array as [n rows][2048 columns]
raw_array=np.loadtxt('raw_data.txt',dtype=int)

avg_array=np.mean(raw_array,0) #averages over zeroth column
x_inc=np.arange(lower_bound,upper_bound)
plt.plot(x_inc[lower_bound,upper_bound],avg_array[lower_bound,upper_bound])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you show us some examples of how it looks?

Comment: I think the `avg` in your plot statement should be `avg_array` (probably happened while copying). Why do you need the slice of `[lower_bound,upper_bound]` for it though? I thought the array was guaranteed to have 2048 columns?

Comment: Three things, `np.mean(raw_array, 0)` averages over the 0th axis, not the 0th column. Second, if why not assign the data to `dtype=numpy.float32` when you read it in, instead of int, finally, `np.arange` is not reliable in many cases you should use `np.linspace` instead.

Comment: @Benjamin, 
1. I didn't realize that was the case, as for the 0th axis vs 0th column. Thank you.
2. I tried that, and it didn't change anything.
3. How could arange be unreliable? I'm not aware. I'll try linspace and get back to you.

Comment: @StefanS, correct about that. It did happen during copying. The reason I need a slice is to be able to zoom in on specific timeframes of the data.

Comment: @Bart this is the averaged data across thousands of data. I would expect it to be smoother! [Noisy Data](http://imgur.com/2tjfoVD)

Comment: @snelltheta, never mind about arange, I was thinking of the case where the step is non-integer: "When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use linspace for these cases."

Comment: Essentially, the code looks good. You can definitely use integers if you know your input is integers. We'll have to see the actual pictures to see your problem. Have you tried to create histograms (bin width = 1) for the columns that you average over? Maybe the integers are not distributed as you think they are and it's the small sample that gives you the wrong idea and the large sample that gives a better representation of reality.

Comment: @StefanS, a part of the actual graph has been posted in reply to Bart. [Here is the link again](http://imgur.com/2tjfoVD).


Also, I've thought about the point you've brought up about whether or not the integers are as distributed as I thought they would be, but the chart is supposed to represent analog voltages, and I doubt that anything as crazy as I've been getting out represents reality when I average it over a large data set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the data that I was averaging had an error (caused by data acquisition program). Basically, more than half of the frames of data collected from the sensor were identical and repeated. This caused the output to approximate a single frame of data, rather than smooth out the large set of data that I thought I had.